При входе в личный кабинет загружается сначала всё без стилей наверно, а потом уже остальное подгружается, как и что надо исправить?
не могу точно сформулировать вопрос, поэтому поставлю пару картинок.
Когда залогинился то при обновлении страницы всегда вперед грузится просто текст (наименования разделов меню) и только потом догружается все остальное. Подскажите где и что надо исправить или настроить. Могу дать доступ посмотреть или скажите какой код надо показать.


Могу дать доступ посмотреть или скажите какой код надо показать. почему кто то должен выпрашивать доступ или код чтобы помочь вам?

так я не знаю просто надо или нет поэтому предложил варианты, я же не знаю какой именно кусок кода давать, я могу и весь сайт архивом скинуть), скажите что надо то я и дам, там например по два файла каждой страницы, еще отдельно меню файл, ну и хедер/футер...

@AndreyZhuravlev немедленно убери доступы, если не хочешь, чтобы ими воспользовались злоумышленники.

Так там у вас сначала подгружается JS только после которого подгружаются стили.

Скажите пожалуйста, это можно исправить, вернее как это исправить,

Попробуйте подгружать css асинхронно.
Вот статья на стаке, где описывается ваш случай https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759272/how-to-load-css-asynchronously

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.
